# visibility of e-mail address

Tags: discussion, email

In [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21500/effect-of-wheel-diameter-on-line-following-robot/21503#21503) Russell publishes his e-mail address because in his profile it is invisible to others than himself. How about making it an option to show or hide this e-mail address?

I'm not for publishing an e-mail address in a question or answer. I think the full discussion may be interesting to others to, and therefore should take place on the site.

Comment: Why do I always get to play the badguy!? "Kortuk will remove it," what about kevin and mark! Spread the hate.

Comment: @Kortuk - LOL! Well, I had to name someone with more authority than I have in this. I really wouldn't know how I got to your name :-)

Comment: Agreed, there should be a straightforward and obvious way to share your email address with fellow participants here. It's entirely reasonable for some exchanges to eventually reach a point where it makes sense for the participants to take it "offline."

Answer (score 4):

If you want to tell the world your email address, you can do it in the comments section of your profile.  You can ramble on quite a bit about yourself apparently, and it's available for other members to see.  What's the problem?

Comment: If there's too much of that rambling the e-mail address may be hard to spot. A fixed location may then be handy.

Comment: @stevenvh: Or don't ramble so much.